# Does Macbook Air (mid 2013) bypass battery after it's charged?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging

I have a MBA mid 2013. I was wondering if a MBA is plugged in charge, does it bypass battery after it's fully charged?

Because while I am working it's always plugged, I wonder how this will affect the actual battery life.

When I was using my laptop, I used to unplug its battery when I was working with AC power in office to preserve its life cycle.

Is there a way to "bypass battery and make MBA mid 2013 to only use AC power from wall"? Or does it do it automatically?

There's [this similar question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/30209/does-the-macbook-air-draw-power-from-the-battery-or-wall-socket-when-the-battery), but it's rather old. Also I'm not sure if anything changed both on hardware and software side since 2010.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how we can know this for sure, but I believe that after fully-charged, it is indeed "bypassed".

Of course after if drops power it could be charging it back up a little bit, but I have never seen that happen.
At least not if judging from the LED indicator on the cable, which remains green at all times